# Install yajl-py on OS X: "Yajl shared object cannot be found. Please install Yajl and confirm it is on your shared lib path."

Tags: macos, yajl

I'm trying to install yajl-py () on my Mac. However, it gives the following error:

```
Yajl shared object cannot be found. Please install Yajl and confirm it is on your shared lib path.
```

I installed yajl via `ports`, so I know it's there, the question is how to get the shared lib in /opt/local/lib into the lib path.

Doing a bit of reading, seems like a bad idea to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I don't see any alternatives. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution (let me know if there are issues with it), but for now I symlinked the dylib file from `/opt/local/lib` to `/user/local/lib` using the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/libyajl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libyajl.dylib
```

Comment: yes this is one way ... also updating LD_LIBRARY_PATH should work and I do not see the problem with that, especially since you installed yajl in a non standard path.

Comment: For those using homebrew: `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/yajl/lib/libyajl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libyajl.dylib`